# How to store user inputs in an array and check if the two array has the same element

Tags: c++, arrays, storing-data, range-checking

I'm trying to make a quiz checker where the user will input their answer and it will automatically check in the array. Any tips?

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
     string aswer[] = { "D", "C", "D", "D", "A"); // 
     char input[5];
     int counter ;
     int points = 0;
     cout << "Welcome and Good luck!\n";

            for (counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
                cout << counter << " Choose from letters A-D: \n";
                cin >> input;
            }
           for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                cout << "\n you enter " << input[i] << endl;
            }
            foreach (char item in answer){
                foreach (char item1 in inputs){
                    If (item == item1){
                    points = points +1  
                }
            }

           }
    return 0;
      }
```

Comment: `cin >> input;` -> `cin >> input[counter];` ?? `string answer { "DCDDA" };`?? `for (auto& item : answer) { for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {if (item == input[i]) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Tips -- be consistent choosing storage. If you are using a `std::string` for the `answer` (not the erroneous array of `std::string` shown), then use a `std::string` for `input` as well. But if you must use a POA (plain old array), that's fine for educational purposes -- you just lack all auto-memory management and bounds protections.

You initialize a [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) as:

```
    std::string answer { "DCDDA" };    /* initialize string (not array of strings) */
```

(**note:** the use of `std::` namespace identifier. See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696))

Don't use *Magic Numbers* in  your code. The `5` you stick in your array declaration and in your loop limit is a *Magic Number*. Instead,

```
#define NCHAR 5     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
    char input[NCHAR];                 /* array of 5 char (why not string?) */
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < NCHAR; i++) {   /* loop taking input */
```

When you loop taking input, validate every input. The user may well generate a manual `EOF` to cancel input with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows). Only increment the count of characters stored after you have validated the input, e.g.

```
    int counter = 0, points = 0;       /* counter and points, initialized zero */
    
    std::cout << "Welcome and Good luck!\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < NCHAR; i++) {   /* loop taking input */
        std::cout << "  " << i << ".  Choose from letters A-D: ";
        if (std::cin >> input[i])       /* validate input */
            counter++;                  /* only increment on successful input */
    }
```

For your output, understand the difference between using `'\n'` and `std::endl`, [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).

When you have items stored in a container (such as `std::string`), you can use a [Range-based for loop (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to loop over each item in the container. To loop over your stored input, you must limit the loop to the number of elements successfully read as input. Use the same `counter` as your comparison limit, e.g.

```
    for (auto& item : answer)           /* range based for-loop over chars in string */
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)   /* loop over counter chars in array */
            if (item == input[i])       /* if the item matches the input char */
                points += 1;            /* add point */
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define NCHAR 5     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main()
{
    std::string answer { "DCDDA" };    /* initialize string (not array of strings) */
    char input[NCHAR];                 /* array of 5 char (why not string?) */
    int counter = 0, points = 0;       /* counter and points, initialized zero */
    
    std::cout << "Welcome and Good luck!\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < NCHAR; i++) {   /* loop taking input */
        std::cout << "  " << i << ".  Choose from letters A-D: ";
        if (std::cin >> input[i])       /* validate input */
            counter++;                  /* only increment on successful input */
    }
    
    std::cout << "\nYou entered:\n";    /* output stored values */
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)   /* looping only 0 to counter */
        std::cout << "  input[" << i << "] : " << input[i] << '\n';
    
    for (auto& item : answer)           /* range based for-loop over chars in string */
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)   /* loop over counter chars in array */
            if (item == input[i])       /* if the item matches the input char */
                points += 1;            /* add point */
    
    std::cout << "\nTotal points: " << points << '\n';  /* output total points */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/points
Welcome and Good luck!

  0.  Choose from letters A-D: A
  1.  Choose from letters A-D: B
  2.  Choose from letters A-D: C
  3.  Choose from letters A-D: D
  4.  Choose from letters A-D: E

You entered:
  input[0] : A
  input[1] : B
  input[2] : C
  input[3] : D
  input[4] : E

Total points: 5
```

Checking maximum points if all characters match:

```
$ ./bin/points
Welcome and Good luck!

  0.  Choose from letters A-D: D
  1.  Choose from letters A-D: C
  2.  Choose from letters A-D: D
  3.  Choose from letters A-D: D
  4.  Choose from letters A-D: A

You entered:
  input[0] : D
  input[1] : C
  input[2] : D
  input[3] : D
  input[4] : A

Total points: 11
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.